# Android studio developer's app

Tags: android

I am developing an app that is filled up with list items. I want to be able to add list items in-app and affect all apps. By that I mean, if i want to add a new list item to all apps, I don't want to do it programmatically and then updating the app. I want to do it in- if possible developer's app.
I don't know how it's usually done but I want people with no programming skills, to be able to add a new list item. I thought of creating a special developers app with a nice UI, but how do I then affect all other apps?

How is this achieved, how is it usually done?

Comment: You just described an admin panel at server side. You need to create a server, which will provide data to your client apps, via REST API for example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using firebase is one of the many ways of achieving what you want. Please research here [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1001467%20%7C%20Firebase*%20Brand%20GENERIC%20%7C%20Global%20%7C%20en%20%7C%20Desk%2BTab%2BMobile%20%7C%20Text%20%7C%20BKWS%20%5B2017%5D&utm_term=%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7a-N7szh1wIVVwiRCh0a2AtMEAAYASAAEgIYCPD_BwE) and come with doubt when implementing your app